# How To Locate Element using selenium web driver when Unique property is 'index'?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, javascript

How To Locate Elements using selenium web driver when only Unique value is 'index'? `Resource-id`,`Class` and `Package`  are not unique.

Below Layout taken from Android UI Automator

[image]

```
Resource-id = android:id/menuitem

Class =       android.widget.RelativeLayout

Package =     android
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium to find an array of elements that share common characteristics such as class names and etc, then indexing through this array to locate the element you want.

```
elementArray = webdriver.findelements(xpath / css selector);
theElement = elementArray[1];
```

Comment: can you please write x path of this code

Comment: Could you please write full code

Comment: This is a viable solution, but is not as elegant, in my opinion, as BountyHunter's answer, which includes the index in the xpath used to locate the element.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write an xpath with index specified. For the example you mentioned, the xpath should look like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='menuitem'])[index]")
```

where index will start from 1, NOT 0

Answer (score 1):

You can write Xpath using index in two different ways.

1. If you want to locate particular element:
   Ex: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='menuitem'])[index]");`
   in this case index will start from '1' and not '0'
2. If you are writing generic Xpath using findElements and getIndex (Using loops)
   Ex: `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='menuitem']").get(index).getText();`
   in this case index will start from '0'